# Multiple lines into single line in Python

Tags: python

I have a file as follows:

```
>abc
AAA
AAA
>dfgg
BBBBB
BBBBB
BB
>zzz
CCCCC
CCC
```

My desired output is:

```
>abc
AAAAAA
>dfgg
BBBBBBBBBBBB
>zzz
CCCCCCCC
```

That is turning multiple lines into a single line.

I wrote the following code:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
currentline = ""
for line in f:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        print line
    else:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        currentline = currentline + line
        print currentline
f.close()
```

Of course, this is not right as the `currentline` keeps on growing until the end. I can't figure out how I can update the `currentline` and print the output as indicated.

I know one option is to read the whole file either with `f.read()` or `f.readlines()` and treat the file as string or list but as the file is very large and each line that doesn't start with '>' can go up to 20 million characters, I thought it's better not to read the whole file into memory at once and treat it line by line. Please let me know what you think of that.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was fine, all you needed to do was find the right place to update `currentline`. You would update after you find the next flag, which in your case was a line that started with `>`.

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
currentline = ""
for line in f:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if currentline != "": print currentline
        print line
        currentline = ""
    else:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        currentline = currentline + line
print currentline
f.close()


Input:

>abc
AAA
AAA
>dfgg
BBBBB
BBBBB
BB
>zzz
CCCCC
CCC

Output:

>abc
AAAAAA
>dfgg
BBBBBBBBBBBB
>zzz
CCCCCCCC

# edited code above and tested it with the below file based on ypnos's comment.
Input:

>abc
AAA
AAA
>dfgg
BBBBB
BBBBB
BB
>
>
>>
>zzz
CCCCC
CCC

Output:

>abc
AAAAAA
>dfgg
BBBBBBBBBBBB
>
>
>>
>zzz
CCCCCCCC
```

EDIT: ypnos made a good point that the above would print unnecessary newlines. I made a small change to the above code and it avoids printing those now. See the new test case above.

Comment: That is almost as good as the solution I already had posted earlier. But you are printing unnecessary newlines in some circumstances.

Comment: I believe the only new line that would appear is just one new line at the beginning of the print

Comment: You can also have additional newlines if you have consecutive lines starting with '>'.

Comment: Good point, I modified my code to avoid that scenario. It will still print lines that have '>', but not unnecessary new lines

Comment: I donvoted it because it is a worse version of what I already had in my answer, before I even improved my answer further. It still prints an unnecessary newline when the input is empty, and it unnecessarily accumulates lines (that is why I improved my answer). So in general it might work but is worse than several other answers and does not add anything distinctive in how the solution works.

Answer (score 4):

A naive solution:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('data.txt') as f:
    for key, group in groupby(f, lambda s: s.startswith('>')):
        print(''.join(s.rstrip('\n') for s in group))
```

This only works if the lines beginning with `>` are all single lines, which they are in your example. To avoid concatenating those you can do something like:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

counter = count()
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for key, group in groupby(f, lambda s: next(counter) if s.startswith('>') else -1):
        print(''.join(s.rstrip('\n') for s in group))
```

The key to this is the key function to `groupby`: `count()` is a generator that simply produces a sequence of integers 0, 1, 2. This means that each `>` line gets its own unique key while all the other lines get a key of `-1` and are grouped together except when a `>` line intervenes.

In fact any expression that keeps the groups unique could be used, it doesn't have to be a counter. For example you could use this:

```
lambda s: object() if s.startswith('>') else None
```

The file iteration and `groupby` are both lazy so groups will be output as soon as the line after the group has been read.

Comment: I like it, although not easy to read. Does this really process and output line-by-line? Can you explain what the count() is doing there?

Comment: @ypnos I've added a bit more explanation and also corrected an error with the counter (though the error doesn't really matter as the code still worked with it in there!)

Comment: Thank you! The only drawback to your solution is then that it will not print line-by-line but group-by-group.

Answer (score 1):

A version that prints everything as soon as it comes in:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    flush = False
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            if flush:
                print('')
            print(line.rstrip('\n'))
            flush = False
        else:
            flush = True
            print(line.rstrip('\n'), end='')
    if flush:
        print('')
```

Comment: This looks like Python 3 where OP obviously uses Python2

Comment: `flush` starts as `False`, and can become `True`, but is never set back to `False`.

Comment: @DSM: thank you! that is relevant when there are multiple lines starting with '>'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        print '\n', line.rstrip('\n')
    else:
        print line.rstrip('\n'), 
f.close()
```

Comment: Haha, even simpler. But don't you produce a newline at the beginning that should not be there? And miss a newline at the very end?

Comment: There is a space character placed in the lines after concatenation. I am not familiar with putting a comma at the end of the print line, could you please explain this?

Comment: That is a trick that works in python2, but not python3, to supress '\n' to be printed at the end. As you said, this solution has problems with additional spaces and newline at beginning, missing newline at end.

Comment: for py3 use print(line.rstrip('\n'), end='')